# war packaging without jetty dependency with sbt

Tags: jetty, war, sbt

I want to build and package my SBT project as .war file. I've found plugin xsbt-web-plugin, but it requires Jetty dependency which I don't need, because I use Apache Tomcat for production and development. All I want from SBT is to package my build to .war file using standard hierarchy. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include the following line in your `build.sbt` file, jetty will only be used for running a container for testing your app in sbt; it will not be included into the war file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.0.4.v20111024" % "container"
```

You don't have to use the container for testing if you don't want to.